# Remove blacklist from spamRATS

Tags: email, email-server, spam, blacklist, blacklist-prevention

I have checked my IP in SpamRATS and the result is the following:

Standards Compliance:

> Does IP Address resolve to a reverse hostname... Passed!
>
> Does IP Address comply with reverse hostname naming convention...Passed!

List Status:

> RATS-Dyna - On the list. Worst Offender Alert
>
> RATS-NoPtr - Not on the list
>
> RATS-Spam - Not on the list

I tried to remove it from their page and it says "That IP Address is not listed." but when I checked it again, it is listed and gives me the above message. 
How can I remove my ip from the list and what will I do so that I will not be listed again.?

please help me on this one.

Comment: It would be useful if you post the actual IP address. See [What information should I include or obfuscate in my posts?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/218590)

Answer (score 9):

SpamRats is a very unreliable blacklist. They basically ignore everyone including ISPs, so there are always a good number of innocent sites listed by their system.

Ignore or remove Spamrats and use the more reliable lists like Spamhaus, SpamCop, Truncate, UCEprotect.

Answer (score 6):

SpamRats is a cheating "company" that is adding whole IP ranges and after than they try to sell you commercial services provided by their official companies ... if you write them an email with demand to stop illegal discreditation of the good name of your company or you will sue them they will remove it within an hour ... personal experience

Comment: This really makes a better comment than an answer: The information is helpful to know, but doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

RATS-Dyna means an IP range not a single IP address.  It is for spammy neighborhoods.  So check who is in charge of that range.  The provider of the range needs to address the individual users.

RATS-NoPtr - Means that your domain and IP reverse lookup are properly set.  Which is a good thing.

In your case you have everything setup correctly but your IP neighbors aren't.  Doesn't mean all of them are bad just a large number.  Contact your provider and scream at them.

Comment: or change provider.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no way to persuade spamrats to unblock your IP.  Their removal tool simply does nothing, and attempts to contact them go unanswered.  You either need to persuade the people you are emailing not to use spamrats, or get yourself a new IP.

Comment: As of 2021, they're asking personally identifiable information (like a passport) of the private MX operator to be sent to them, along with information about "what kind of email is being sent" to be taken off the "worst offenders" list which is simply a huge subnet. That organization has nothing to do with protecting anyone from spam. Everyone's much better off using credible blacklists that act responsibly such as Spamhaus.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool

http://mxtoolbox.com/supertool.aspx

to make sure your server is setup properly. Likely you just missed a DNS record.

"If you are on RATS-Dyna, your reverse DNS is probably not set up correctly."

http://spamrats.com/removal.php

Comment: so you are saying we just got the reverse DNS wrong?
but what in blacklist.org it say here that "Reverse DNS (PTR) exists and claims to be: server.ourserver.co." lso in dyna.spamrats.com "Does IP Address resolve to a reverse hostname... Passed!", "Does IP Address comply with reverse hostname naming convention... Passed!"

Comment: The user stated in his original post that his reverse DNS is setup properly: "Does IP Address resolve to a reverse hostname... Passed!"

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a DNS problem, the blacklisted IP may be a 3rd party IP and not yours. Check your routing configuration to see if any packets are redirected via another than default normal path. They may explain why your original IP is clean but mails are still blocked with blacklisted IP.

Answer (score 0):

RBLs in general provide a valuable service, but Spamrats use a blunderbuss where a pea-shooter would be more appropriate. They block not just an offender's ip address but the entire class C address range that the offender comes from. This is not the way responsible RBL providers behave and I for one wouldn't choose to use this outfit at all. Just so you know I'm not alone in having this opinion: https://www.cartika.com/blog/we-love-rbl-providers-but-every-few-years-someone-like-spamrats-comes-along/

Comment: link dead 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, the 'blunderbuss' only comes out when sufficient IP(s) in the class C all are detected as being a spam source, however the SpamRats! team is very good about helping you get unlisted if your server is properly configured, even if it is in the middle of a class C full of spammers.